# How to create a map<k,v> between first and last nested object using Java streams?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Assuming I have the following classes:

```
class A {
    int id;
    List<B> b;
}

class B {
    int id;
}
```

I want to create a map between  A.id to the list of B.id (`Map<Integer, List<Integer>>` , where key = `A.id`, and `List<Integer>` corresponds to the list of B.id fields for each A ). I tried various combinations of `Collectors.groupingBy` and `Collectors.mapping`, but to no effect. Can somebody help me out ?

Answer (score 5):

You may use the `toMap` collector with a merge function to solve this problem. Here's how it looks.

```
Map<Integer, List<Integer>> resultMap = aList.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(A::getId,
        a -> a.getB().stream().map(B::getId)
            .collect(Collectors.toList()), (l1, l2) -> {
                    l1.addAll(l2);
                    return l1;
                }));
```

However, if a given set of A objects have distinct id values, then you can merely dispense with the merge function, which is the third argument to the `toMap` collector. Here's the simplified version.

```
Map<Integer, List<Integer>> resultMap = aList.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(A::getId, 
        a -> a.getB().stream().map(B::getId)
            .collect(Collectors.toList())));
```

Comment: why not just `toMap()` collector `list.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(A::getId, a -> new ArrayList<>(a.getB().stream().map(B::getId)
                        .collect(Collectors.toList())), (l1, l2) -> {
                    l1.addAll(l2);
                    return l1;
                }));`

Comment: I have updated the answer. Thanks for the feedback. @HadiJ

Answer (score 0):

```
List<A> aList;
//initialize aList here...
Map<String, List<Integer>> aMap = aList.stream().collect(
        Collectors.toMap(element -> element.id,
                         element -> element.b
                                 .stream()
                                 .map(b -> b.id)
                                 .collect(Collectors.toList())
        )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in java-8 using [Collectors.mapping](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#mapping-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-) to only map `List<B> b` while groping and then [Collectors.collectingAndThen](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#collectingAndThen-java.util.stream.Collector-java.util.function.Function-) for the final transformation of value `List<List<B>>` to `List<Integer>`

```
Map<Integer, List<Integer>> result = list.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(A::getId,
                    Collectors.mapping(A::getB, Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toList(),
                            l -> l.stream().flatMap(List::stream).map(B::getId).collect(Collectors.toList())))));
```

Answer (score 0):

Java 9 added [`flatMapping`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#flatMapping-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-) collector, which is perfect for this:

```
// using static imports of various Collectors
listOfA.stream().collect(
  groupingBy(
    A::getId,
    flatMapping(
      a -> a.getB().stream().map(B::getId),
      toList()
    )
  )
);
```